# Why map and filter are not as 'interactive' in Python 3.x as in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to program interactively in Python 2.7 with IDLE. In 2.7, when I did things like:

```
map(... some fn ..., ... some collection ...)
```

or

```
filter(... some fn ..., ... some collection ...)
```

I got the result as a collection resulting from applying the function.

After upgrading to Python 3.2, when I do the same I just get "Filter object" or "Map object" and have to manually iterate through the collection to see the result.

Was this intended and do you know any Python 3.2 IDE that will behave like old IDLE with respect to printing function outputs? I'm basically looking for "REPL for Python".

Comment: The answer to the actual question, as given below by Martijn, is factual.  With the red-herring of Idle removed, I believe this duplicates other questions about the change to map, filter, range, and other builtin functions.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with IDLE; the [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) functions have changed in Python 3 and now return an iterator instead of a list:

> `filter`: Construct an iterator...
>
> `map`: Return an iterator...

Use `list(filter(...))` and `list(map(...))` if you want to see the results as lists.

Alternatively, you can use list comprehensions:

```
[func(item) for item in somelist]  # same as list(map(func, somelist))
[item for item in somelist if func(item)]  # same as filter(func, somelist))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm upset by this. I will revert to 2.7.

Comment: @PiotrGorak: Don't be. The `map()` and `filter()` functions just got a whole lot more efficient. I've provided list comprehension alternatives too.